# Sonicwall SSLVPN Godaddy Certificate Trust Issues

Tags: certificate, godaddy, sonicwall

Okay,  I have a Sonicwall E5500 I'm trying to get SSLVPN working with my Godaddy SSL wildcard certificate. It seems to only throw errors when I try to use this certificate for the SSLVPN port. https://vpn.oivov.com:4433

When connecting to the Sonicwall Administration page from the public web the certificate is trusted and valid in all browsers. https://vpn.oivov.com:333

xttp://i.imgur.com/4PfQFkz.jpg

However when this same certificate is applied to the SSLVPN port of the same device it comes up as a broken chain and is not trusted by at least android devices but probably all others.

xttp://i.imgur.com/Y9jycfE.jpg
xttp://i.imgur.com/MPnYRln.png
xttp://i.imgur.com/1YkgeSI.png

SSL Shopper and Qualy's say the certificate chain is broken but it has the rest of the chain, its just not giving it out for SSLVPN and I'm not sure why. It shows the cert as validated so why isn't it acting like it for SSLVPN?

My imported certificates, Root, Intermediate, and Site
xttp://i.imgur.com/WM59M8L.jpg

These are the preinstalled certificates on Sonicwall E5500.

xttp://i.imgur.com/fGZYdBb.jpg

Please help!  Thank you.

Comment: Followed https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-sonicwall-ssl-vpn.htm ? (even if digicert, it show how with the sonicwall)

Comment: I believe the process has changed a bit where you no longer make or are even allowed to upload a zip file into the Sonicwall.  This is the error, invalid format. I tried it, anything to fix this.   Thanks for the suggestion. 

xttp://i.imgur.com/JfAtiSt.png

Comment: Looks like you got it working, all you need to do is import the PFX

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  the resolution is that SonicWALL needed to install a hotfix on my device.

I had to pay around 400$ to get Service and Support for a day and then I was able to put in a ticket with them. They came back to me tonight with a new firmware: SonicOS Enhanced 5.9.1.5-8o

They said this is an issue on most Gen 5 units but its fixed on Gen 6 units. In the meantime you may need to get this update in order for your certificates to validate properly in SSLVPN.

Thanks for help guys.